# How to do two clauses WHERE inside a nested WITH

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following code:

```
$sectors = Sector::where('company_id', $id)
                 ->where('status', '0')
                 ->with('charges.levels')
                 ->get();
```

and I need 3 conditions

- Status of sector be 0
- Status of charges be 0
- Status of levels be 0

So I wanna know:

- How to use a WHERE that search the status of charges 0 and the status
  of levels 0 when they are in a nested with: ->with('charges.levels')

The code have the following relationships:

- A sector has many charges and a charge belongs to a sector
- A charge has many levels and a level belongs to a charge

So, I wanna bring all levels where status of level is 0, status of charge is 0 and the status of sector is 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query on the relations like this when you are eager loading:

```
$sectors = Sector::where('company_id', $id)
    ->with([
        'charges' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('status', 0);
        },
        'charges.levels' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('status', 0);
        }
    ])
    ->get();
```

For more information about constraining eager loading: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

Comment: so inside this `$query`, i can do a `->with(['levels' => function($sndQuery)])` ?

Comment: Keep in mind that filtering the `->with()` clauses will not constrain the initial `Sector` query; need to use `->whereHas()` for that.

Comment: This will not constrain your results.  You'd have to perform some additional operations to filter out any where the relations are empty.  Untested, but something like `$sectors = $sectors->filter(function (Sector $sector) {return (!$sector->charges->isEmpty() && !$sector->charges->levels->isEmpty());});`.  (Given the plurality of your relation names, I'm assuming these will be collections.  Otherwise, you'd be checking for null values rather than `isEmpty()`.)

Answer (score 0):

```
$sectors = Sector::where('company_id', $id)->where('status', 0)
    ->whereHas('charges', function (\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query) {
        $query->where('status', 0)
            ->whereHas('levels', function (\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query) {
                $query->where('status', 0);
            });
    })->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Be careful with this though.  Eloquent doesn't do JOIN statements (except in the case of `belongsToMany` relations).  `with()` merely executes a separate queries that uses `IN()` statements populated by previous ones, and `whereHas()` will produce a subquery.  So the above will produce a query that'll look something along the lines of:

```
SELECT *
FROM sector
WHERE
    status = 0
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM charge
        WHERE
            charge.sector_id = sector.id
            AND status = 0
            AND EXISTS (
                SELECT *
                FROM levels
                WHERE
                    levels.charge_id = charge.id
                    AND status = 0
            )
    );
```

I don't know about other DB engines, but MySQL isn't terribly good at handling subqueries.  If you were to do an `EXPLAIN` on that, the number of initial entries that get pulled for the query would be limited only by `sector.status`, which can be a problem if that table is large and/or `sector.status` is not indexed.  This is as opposed to say, a `JOIN` query that could get the full benefit of combining search criteria.  With `JOIN`s, additional criteria typically improve performance, but the reverse is true with `EXITS`s.  So you might have better luck using this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#joins.